# Integrating d3.js Trend Chart (Area + Line) as data studio community visualisation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, looker-studio, data-studio-custom-visuals

I am a data scientist. Mostly use python and SQL for code. I am using data studio for visualizations.So I am unfamiliar to JS. I know-how [data studio community visualizations](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-visualization/#0)  works. I want to make this [chart](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/33a9e350516da54a5d4f)(without markers). I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56556965/integrating-d3-js-sunburst-as-data-studio-community-visualisation). I tried but didn't get success. Can anybody with me on this? or refer me d3.js data studio integration resources.

Comment: It is difficult to provide help without knowing exactly where you are facing issues. Could you please explain what you meant by "didn't get success". Where/when exactly is the process not working for you?

Comment: Please see the below answer.

Comment: Am I right to assume that you are trying to understand how the data object works in Data Studio POST message and how to use that in your viz code?

Comment: yes. Basically how to use d3.js in data studio without much knowledge of js.

Comment: That would be very difficult. Community Visualizations need some basic Javascript understanding. It isn't possible to directly copy-paste a javascript snippet and get that to work with Community Viz. You will need to update your config, change the data model, handle the setting, as well as manage viz resizing. All of that will need to be done through mostly Javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really not sure what you want but for the chart without markers here what I think you want:

```js
function addAxesAndLegend(svg, xAxis, yAxis, margin, chartWidth, chartHeight) {
      var legendWidth = 200,
        legendHeight = 100;

      // clipping to make sure nothing appears behind legend
      svg
        .append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "axes-clip")
        .append("polygon")
        .attr(
          "points",
          -margin.left +
            "," +
            -margin.top +
            " " +
            (chartWidth - legendWidth - 1) +
            "," +
            -margin.top +
            " " +
            (chartWidth - legendWidth - 1) +
            "," +
            legendHeight +
            " " +
            (chartWidth + margin.right) +
            "," +
            legendHeight +
            " " +
            (chartWidth + margin.right) +
            "," +
            (chartHeight + margin.bottom) +
            " " +
            -margin.left +
            "," +
            (chartHeight + margin.bottom)
        );

      var axes = svg.append("g").attr("clip-path", "url(#axes-clip)");

      axes
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + chartHeight + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

      axes
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Time (s)");

      var legend = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (chartWidth - legendWidth) + ", 0)");

      legend
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "legend-bg")
        .attr("width", legendWidth)
        .attr("height", legendHeight);

      legend
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "outer")
        .attr("width", 75)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", 10);

      legend
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 115)
        .attr("y", 25)
        .text("5% - 95%");

      legend
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "inner")
        .attr("width", 75)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", 40);

      legend
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 115)
        .attr("y", 55)
        .text("25% - 75%");

      legend
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "median-line")
        .attr("d", "M10,80L85,80");

      legend
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 115)
        .attr("y", 85)
        .text("Median");
    }

    function drawPaths(svg, data, x, y) {
      var upperOuterArea = d3.svg
        .area()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.date) || 1;
        })
        .y0(function(d) {
          return y(d.pct95);
        })
        .y1(function(d) {
          return y(d.pct75);
        });

      var upperInnerArea = d3.svg
        .area()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.date) || 1;
        })
        .y0(function(d) {
          return y(d.pct75);
        })
        .y1(function(d) {
          return y(d.pct50);
        });

      var medianLine = d3.svg
        .line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.date);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y(d.pct50);
        });

      var lowerInnerArea = d3.svg
        .area()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.date) || 1;
        })
        .y0(function(d) {
          return y(d.pct50);
        })
        .y1(function(d) {
          return y(d.pct25);
        });

      var lowerOuterArea = d3.svg
        .area()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.date) || 1;
        })
        .y0(function(d) {
          return y(d.pct25);
        })
        .y1(function(d) {
          return y(d.pct05);
        });

      svg.datum(data);

      svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "area upper outer")
        .attr("d", upperOuterArea)
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)");

      svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "area lower outer")
        .attr("d", lowerOuterArea)
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)");

      svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "area upper inner")
        .attr("d", upperInnerArea)
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)");

      svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "area lower inner")
        .attr("d", lowerInnerArea)
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)");

      svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "median-line")
        .attr("d", medianLine)
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#rect-clip)");
    }


    function startTransitions(svg, chartWidth, chartHeight, rectClip, x) {
      rectClip
        .transition()
        .duration(4000)
        .attr("width", chartWidth);
    }

    function makeChart(data) {
      var svgWidth = 960,
        svgHeight = 500,
        margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 40 },
        chartWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        chartHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var x = d3.time
          .scale()
          .range([0, chartWidth])
          .domain(
            d3.extent(data, function(d) {
              return d.date;
            })
          ),
        y = d3.scale
          .linear()
          .range([chartHeight, 0])
          .domain([
            0,
            d3.max(data, function(d) {
              return d.pct95;
            })
          ]);

      var xAxis = d3.svg
          .axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .innerTickSize(-chartHeight)
          .outerTickSize(0)
          .tickPadding(10),
        yAxis = d3.svg
          .axis()
          .scale(y)
          .orient("left")
          .innerTickSize(-chartWidth)
          .outerTickSize(0)
          .tickPadding(10);

      var svg = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      // clipping to start chart hidden and slide it in later
      var rectClip = svg
        .append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "rect-clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", 0)
        .attr("height", chartHeight);

      addAxesAndLegend(svg, xAxis, yAxis, margin, chartWidth, chartHeight);
      drawPaths(svg, data, x, y);
      startTransitions(svg, chartWidth, chartHeight, rectClip, x);
    }

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
    d3.json(
      "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rkirsling/33a9e350516da54a5d4f/raw/100dde6bc011fa2604f2c0fb2c160501e220a201/data.json",
      function(error, rawData) {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return;
        }

        var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: parseDate(d.date),
            pct05: d.pct05 / 1000,
            pct25: d.pct25 / 1000,
            pct50: d.pct50 / 1000,
            pct75: d.pct75 / 1000,
            pct95: d.pct95 / 1000
          };
        });

        makeChart(data);
      }
    );
```

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 700);

svg {
  font: 14px "Open Sans";
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  fill: #000;
}

.axis .tick line {
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.area {
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.area.outer,
.legend .outer {
  fill: rgba(230, 230, 255, 0.8);
  stroke: rgba(216, 216, 255, 0.8);
}

.area.inner,
.legend .inner {
  fill: rgba(127, 127, 255, 0.8);
  stroke: rgba(96, 96, 255, 0.8);
}

.median-line,
.legend .median-line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

.legend .legend-bg {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.marker.client .marker-bg,
.marker.client path {
  fill: rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.8);
  stroke: rgba(255, 127, 0, 0.8);
  stroke-width: 3;
}

.marker.server .marker-bg,
.marker.server path {
  fill: rgba(0, 153, 51, 0.8);
  stroke: rgba(0, 153, 51, 0.8);
  stroke-width: 3;
}

.marker path {
  fill: none;
}

.legend text,
.marker text {
  fill: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.marker text {
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Trend Chart (Area + Line)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you much Mamoun Othman for the great answer! But i have one doubt here ,in [community visualizations](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-visualization/#13) they are passing **data** in function(in myViz.js) and defining fields in myViz.json so when we open this in data studio it takes values from data source(which is in tabular form) automatically.But here you are taking data source from gist.githubusercontent.com. Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: @AamirSiddiqui, you are welcome, the thing is I don't know much about Data studio, but I know d3js and data visualization, I will take a look at it once I have time! will let you know.